# Problema al agregar elementos a un diccionario en Python

Tags: python

Reciban un cordial saludo.

En esta oportunidad me dirijo a ustedes con la finalidad de obetener algo de informacion con respecto los diccionarios en Python.

Resulta que estoy tratando de realizar un diccionario con los datos de un archivo.txt el cual tiene varios datos (que deseo colocar como claves de diccionario) repetidos. Estos datos los transformo en una lista pero al momento de crear el diccionario, la sentencia me omite los datos repetidos, es decir, si son 6 elementos de los cuales 3 son repetidos, el resultado final es un diccionario con 3 elementos o items.

Por favor me podrian guiar en este problema particular?? Como hago para crear el diccionario sin omitir ningun dato asi sean repetidos??

Gracias de antemano por su colaboracion.

Saludos!!

[image: Archivo txt]

```
from os import strerror

try:
    archivo = input("Ingrese el nombre del Archivo del Profesor jekyll: ")

    stream = open(archivo, 'rt', encoding = 'UTF-8')

    lista_key = []
    lista_values = []

    for linea in stream:
        linea = linea.rstrip('\n').split(',')
        linea = tuple(linea)
        diccionario = dict({linea[0]:linea[1]})
        keys = list(diccionario.keys())
        values = list(diccionario.values())
        lista_key.append(keys[0])
        lista_values.append(float(values[0]))
    print(lista_key)
    print(lista_values)

    myDict = list(zip(lista_key, lista_values))



    

    stream.close()  
except IOError as exc:
    print("Error al abrir el archivo: ", strerror(exc.errno))
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para incluir el código y el contenido del archivo. Sin eso, es puro especular.

Comment: ¿Estás consciente de que al final estás obteniendo una lista de tuplas (`myDict = list(zip(lista_key, lista_values))` y no un diccionario)?

Comment: los diccionarios no permiten claves repetidas, la solución más simple es hacer una clave auto incrementable y poner como valor los datos que tienes.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es guardar en las claves del diccionario los nombres, ¿qué querrías que apareciera en `diccionario["John Smith"]`? Si quieres que te aparezcan ambos valores, deberías asociar una lista a cada item del diccionario. Así el valor de ese elemento sería la lista `[5,2]`. ¿Es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: Lo siento el codigo al final es: dict(zip(lista_key, lista_values))